# Filtering Listviews based on text in edit text

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` in one my my android app's activity and i have added a `EditText` in same activity. I want to filter the `ListView` data based on the text entered in `EditText`.

To fill data inside `ListView`, i have implemented a custom adapter class that extends `BaseAdapter`. To filter the `ListView`, i have written `filter` method in this class

**CustomAdapter Class**

**PS.** I have removed all the methods implemented in this class that were unrelated to the problem.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Contact> contactsList;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Contact> filteredList = null;

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> list, Context cont) {
    this.contactsList = list;
    this.context = cont;
    this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.filteredList.addAll(contactsList);
}

//METHOD TO FILTER LISTVIEW
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase();
    contactsList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        //contactsList.addAll(filteredList);
        contactsList = filteredList;
    }
    else
    {
        for (Contact wp : filteredList) {
            if (wp.getUsername().toLowerCase().contains(charText)) {
                contactsList.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

### Question

Inside the first `if-statement`, i have following statement

```
contactsList.addAll(filteredList);
```

Now, as i understand, `addAll` method copies the references of objects from `filteredList` in to `contactsList`. So this is same as

```
contactsList = filteredList;
```

Now if i inside my `filter` method, if i replace

```
contactsList.addAll(filteredList);
```

with

```
contactsList = filteredList;
```

this method no longer filters the `ListView` data.

My question is **WHY** `contactsList = filteredList;` doesn't works ? Is my understanding of `addAll` method wrong ?

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<Contact> { ...` and override its `onBind()` and `matches()` methods, filtering is done as always: `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of addall method is wrong, it doesn't copies references of object, instead it copies each object data from the collection(arraylist).

Checkout here [enter link description here](http://www.javacjava.com/ArrayListAddAll.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should take inspiration from Android's ArrayAdapter. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#543

Comment: I will post a better answer with actual code later.